# Minors of a positive definite matrix are positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> All main minors of a positive definite matrix are positive definite as
>   well and therefore $A$ is  strictly invertible.

All I know about positive-definiteness is that for the symmetric matrix $A$ the following inequality holds:

$$x^TAx>0, \forall x(\neq 0) \in \mathbb R^3$$

Could you please give me some hints as to how can I prove the above theorem, specially its second part, what does  positive-definiteness have to do with being invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's fairly straight-forward actually, naturally depending on how much you want to show. Do you take the following as given?

> If $\mathbf{A}$ is non-invertible, then there exists a non-zero vector
>   $\mathbf{x}$ such that $\mathbf{Ax}=\boldsymbol{0}$.

If you do, then it shouldn't be too problematic.

If $\mathbf{A}$ is *not* invertible, then that means there is a vector such that $\mathbf{Ax}=\boldsymbol{0}$. Thus, $\mathbf{x}^\prime \mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{x}^\prime \boldsymbol{0}=0$. But, if $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite, then $\mathbf{x}^\prime \mathbf{Ax}>0$. So $\mathbf{A}$ cannot be both non-invertible and positive definite. Hence, it must be invertible if it is positive definite.

Edit: This only addresses the second part.

Comment: Great, thank you for your detailed answer. I have no problem with the second part now, but the problem with the first part still remains.

Comment: @Gigili Maybe this could be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: That answers my first question, thank you.

Comment: One last question, when we write $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&A_{21}^T\\A_{21}&A_{22}\end{bmatrix}$, then $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ are minors, right? Could you tell me how they're constructed?

Comment: @Gigili All of them are minors, but $a_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are *principal* minors and $a_{11}$ and $A$ are *leading* principal minors. A minor $M_{i, j}$ is the matrix with row $i$ and column $j$ deleted. If $i=j$ then it's a principal minor. The leading principal minors are $k\times k$ squares beginning at the top left corner of the original matrix. $a_{11}$ is the $(1, 1)$ element, $A_{21}$ a row vector with the elements from $(2, 1)$ to $(n, 1)$ and $A_{22}$ is the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ square matrix consisting of the bottom right $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ square of $A$.

Comment: For the first part in steps: 1) any principal submatrix of an SPD matrix is SPD (directly using the definition of SPDness), 2) an SPD matrix has positive eigenvalues, 3) determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues (and hence positive if they're positive).

Comment: $A_{21}$ is a minor of $A$ with the second row and first column deleted, correct? How is it the row vector that you described above? I don't get it.

Comment: @Gigili Hmm, yes I think that might have been incorrect. $a_{11}$ is a scalar. So for $A$ to have $n$ rows, $A_{21}$ must contain $(n-1)$ rows. Since $a_{11}$ has 1 column, so must $A_{21}$. So rather, I should have said that $a_{11}$ is the leading principal minor for $(1, 1)$ (I'm not sure how to denote leading principal minors). And $A_{22}$ is the minor $M_{11}$. Note that it is neither leading principal or principal. But, your observation that $A_{21}$ is not a minor is correct! Good catch :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informative responses. I appreciate it.